# Is it possible to request JavaScript code from the backend and run it on the frontend?

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, backend

Is there any possibility of being able to execute JavaScript code that we request in the backend within the frontend?

It's a pretty crazy idea and I've been thinking about it for a long time. It would be an API that returns code that runs on the client. Is this really possible?

Comment: ofcourse, this is how the web works, you access an endpoint and it returns content, whether its dynamically creating/loading the content or loading it from file the client doesn't know

Comment: Have you tried doing it? Seems like you could test this.

Comment: I'm curious how you think the javascript code that runs this website got to your computer? And how that's different from your question?

Comment: Do you mean you want to load some code after the page has been parsed? There are a couple of ways to do it, you can create a script tag dynamically, you can import modules or load JSONP.

Comment: As @Teemu mentions you can but think about why exactly do you need to load code afterwards in the first place? Almost always it should be sufficient to include whatever code is needed to the script tag of your index.html file.

Comment: What I had in mind was to be able to load a javascript code coming from the back-end in the front-end, and in fact I did it with express. Once the api call is made, the resulting result (the code in the form of a script) is executed with a native javascript function that is eval (). Thank you very much for trying to contribute, but I have managed to resolve it myself!

Comment: It's notable, that you've to be very careful with `eval`. If the server response contains any client-feeded data (at any point of the lifetime of the data, even when gathered from your own database), `eval` is very vulnerable to XSS attacks, it's impossible to sanitize data which is executable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are thinking about some dynamic code that can differ in each API request's response, then perhaps you can use the **eval** function in JavaScript.

Refer to [this book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/scope%20%26%20closures/ch2.md#eval) for details.

Comment: @ByMarcosDesigns This may answer the question, but I wouldn't recommend this approach. It muddles the concerns of the backend and frontend. Imagine your backend code changes. Will your frontend have to change now as well? And vice versa. Just keep them separate. Backend returns data. Frontend decides what to do with it. Or maybe consider server side rendering.